# DataGridView if checkbox checked enable button, else disable

Tags: c#, checkbox, datagridview

I want to enable the button, when the user has checked a checkbox in the datagridview. I have a checkbox column. The button is not in the datagridview. The button is default enable = false.

My problem: when the user check the checkbox, the button is enabled, but when the user uncheck the checkbox, the button still remain to enable.

my code:

```
void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    this.MainForm.dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
}


void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.MainForm.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Check" && e.RowIndex != -1)
    {            
        this.MainForm.btnUpdate.Enabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        this.MainForm.btnUpdate.Enabled = false;
    }
}


void dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

private void dataGridView1_CellMouseUp(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0 && e.RowIndex > -1)
    {
        this.MainForm.dataGridView1.EndEdit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you debug the code and check if `if (this.MainForm.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Check" && e.RowIndex != -1)` is returning true of false and why?

Answer (score 0):

Check this place and fix it according to your components. Here is a hotfix

```
    void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.MainForm.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Check" && e.RowIndex != -1)
            {
                //here should be a code for enable/disable button, for ex
                this.MainForm.btnUpdate.Enabled = !this.MainForm.btnUpdate.Enabled;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Yes, but this code do the thing to disable the button, where there are others checkbox checked in the column

Comment: describe here an expected behavior

Comment: I check for example 3 checkbox in the column, then I want to uncheck a checkbox (there are yet 2 checkbox checked), when I uncheck a checkbox and others are still checked, then the button is "disabled"

Comment: maybe you will have to implement a counter, or check number of checked rows manually using underlying datatable

Comment: I will try. Thanks

Comment: I can't do this. Do not work. Can you show me an example? I am new to c#

Answer (score 0):

i think u missed the if-checked statement...
How about

```
if (this.MainForm.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Check" && e.RowIndex != -1 && this.MainForm.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Cells[e.RowIndex].value.ToString() == "True")
{
    //enable button
}
else
{
   //disable button
}
```

Comment: hile this code snippet may solve the question, [including a detailed explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.